# Why isn't [ "$(cat file)" = "$contents" ] true when contents (like the file) ends in a newline?

Tags: bash, shell

```
$ a='a
'
$ echo -n "$a" | md5sum
60b725f10c9c85c70d97880dfe8191b3  -
$ echo -n "$a" > foo
$ cat foo | md5sum
60b725f10c9c85c70d97880dfe8191b3  -
$ [ "$(cat foo)" == "$a" ] || echo false
false
```

What is happening? Why aren't these equal?

Comment: @arco444, does `echo -n "$a"` contain a newline or not?

Comment: As an aside, `==` isn't guaranteed to work with `[`; the only string comparison operator in the POSIX specification is `=`. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html; in `[[ ]]` you're guaranteed to have ksh extensions that bash has since picked up, but in `[ ]` you're depending on undefined behavior.

Comment: As another aside, `echo -n` isn't actually guaranteed to have the behavior you expect from it, either. It's much safer from a portability perspective to use `printf '%s' "$a"`; see the spec for `echo` at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html, particularly the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections. (Pull quote: "*It is not possible to use `echo` portably across all POSIX systems unless both `-n` (as the first argument) and escape sequences are omitted.*")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because `$( )` trims trailing newlines. From the [bash reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution) (emphasis added):

> Bash performs the expansion by executing *command* in a subshell environment and replacing the command substitution with the standard output of the command, **with any trailing newlines deleted**.

You can see this directly by printing the value of `$(cat foo)`:

```
$ echo "'$a'"
'a
'
$ echo "'$(cat foo)'"
'a'
```

...note that with `$( )`, the closing single-quote winds up on the same line as the "a", meaning there's no newline after the "a". Also,

```
$ [ "$(cat foo)" = "a" ] && echo true || echo false
true
```

Note that that's comparing against the string "a", which does not contain a newline; not the variable `$a`, which does contain a newline.

Comment: Might use `=` rather than `==` to improve portability to baseline-POSIX `test` implementations, or `[[ ]]` rather than `[ ]` to make dependence on extensions explicit.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Good point; I switched it to the portable (baseline POSIX) syntax.

Comment: @GordonDavisson, is there some way to capture the full contents of the `foo` file in the shell? I.e. a `"$(cat foo)"` but without stripping newlines?

Comment: @PaulDraper, as long as it doesn't contain NUL literals, yes. `IFS= read -r -d '' contents <foo || [[ $contents ]]` will do the trick. If the file *does* contain NUL literals it's trickier, since the shell uses C strings (which can't themselves contain NULs), so you need a different structure (ie. an array of NUL-separated pieces, and a string for any "tail" that may be present after the last piece).

Comment: @PaulDraper, ...*however*, I really think that question should be a question of its own, separately asked, not folded into this one; someone trying to figure out how to read a file in bash without trimming the trailing newlines probably won't pay attention to something titled "trouble with shell equality" in their search results.

Comment: @PaulDraper BTW if you're concerned with strings getting mangled, don't use `echo` (and especially not `echo -n` -- some versions print "-n" as part of the string)! To print a variable without mangling, use `printf "%s" "$a"`.

Answer (score 4):

The variable `$a` that you're comparing against inside the test contains a newline, whereas the result of `$(cat file)` doesn't, because the trailing newline is removed from command substitutions.

This can be verified by using `set -x`:

```
[ "$(cat foo)" = "$a" ] || echo false
++ cat foo
+ '[' a = 'a
' ']'
+ echo false
```

Answer (score 2):

Command substitution strips out **all the trailing newlines** from the file content.

You can do this to read file data back into a variable:

```
a='a
'

# if you have BASH >= 4 then use
mapfile arr < foo
IFS=
b="${arr[*]}"

# or else read file content into a variable and append a new line after each read
# b=; while read -r; do b+="$REPLY"$'\n'; done < foo


# now compare
[[ $b == $a ]] && echo true || echo false
true

# or check content
declare -p a b
declare -- a="a
"
declare -- b="a
"

# using printf
printf 'a=%q;b=%q\n' "$a" "$b"
a=$'a\n';b=$'a\n'
```